# Hide a video and listen its audio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video.js

I'm trying to hide my video player to simulate a only audio execution. I don't want to see any player in my `.jsp` page. I'm using VideoJS as player.

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="player-container">
    <audio id="player"
           class="video-js"
           autoplay="autoplay" 
           preload="auto" 
           width="640" 
           height="380"
           data-setup='{}'>
    <source src="path/to/my/video" type='video/mp4'/>
    </audio>
</div>
```

To achive my target I tried different solutions but they didn't work properly.

The first one was to use `JQuery` to set width and height of my player:

```
$("#player-container").width(1).height(1);
```

But in this way on IE11 and Mozilla Firefox the video does not load. It needs at least 5 as width and height but then it becomes visible.

Then I tried to use `.hide()` of JQuery:

```
$("#video-js-player-container").hide();
```

but in this way my video does not start at all.

What can I do to hide the player listening just the audio of the video?

Comment: `opacity: 0;` or `visibility: hidden;`. Or use positioning to move the video off screen

Comment: Why don't you just load the thing programmatically instead of manually adding something to the DOM you don't need?

Comment: are you streaming? What's the sense of using videoJS?

Comment: Could you extract the audio, then use `<audio>`?

Comment: @LuudJacobs Thank you, your tips was good, I got an idea :)

Comment: Not perfect but you can also set it to a `relative` position, with a negative `top` and `left` so it's not on screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can experiment with a few different CSS values to hide the video.

```
#player-container {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;

    /* somewhat hacky */
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
    /* or */
    clip-path: polygon(0px 0px,0px 0px,0px 0px,0px 0px);
}
```

Try playing around with any of those in your CSS, and determine which one works best in your situation.